# 401 error when invoking asp.net service from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, web, http-status-code-401

I've been stuck on this for quite a bit, I keep getting a 401 error when calling an asp.net web service from c# server side code. Web service is hosted on a remote server, I get its address from config file (Wrapper Service). Whenever I call it, I get a 401 error, even though I can invoke web service method from web browser. Here's the code:

```
    private string getCode(string name)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
        string request = getRequestXML(name);
        string response = ExecuteRequest(request);
        if (response != "")
        {
            xmlResponse.LoadXml(ExecuteRequest(request));
            return xmlResponse.GetElementsByTagName("roaming")[0].InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return "error getting password";
        }
    }

    private string getRequestXML(string userName)
    {
        var sr = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+
           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>"+
           "<soap:Body>"+
           "<GetAccountInfo xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>"+
           "<loginName>"+userName+"</loginName>"+
           "</GetAccountInfo>"+
           "</soap:Body>"+
           "</soap:Envelope>";
        return sr;

    }

    private string ExecuteRequest(string soapStr)
    {


        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WraperService"]);
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/" + "GetAccountInfo" + "\"");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {

            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(soapStr);
            }
        }

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            //XDocument ResultXML = XDocument.Parse(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 401 error means you are unauthorized. Are you passing your credentials properly?

Comment: Do I need to do this? When I try to access and invoke the web service from a web browser, it all works just fine, I'm am not asked for any credentials

Comment: I would inspect the headers the browser sends compared to the headers you send, and see what the difference is then.